# Why can we consider the Brownian motion as being a mapping into the space of continuous functions, even though its paths are only a.s. continuous?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$. By definition of $B$, for $\operatorname{P}$-almost every $\omega\in\Omega$ $$[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto X_t(\omega)\tag{1}$$ is continuous. Generally, a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t\in I}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ with $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ can be viewed as a mapping $$X:\Omega\mapsto\mathbb{R}^I\;,\;\;\;\omega\mapsto \left(t\mapsto X_t(\omega)\right)\tag{2}$$ I've frequently read that $B$ is considered to be a mapping $\Omega\to C\left([0,\infty)\right)$, where $C(I)$ is the space of continuous functions $I\to\mathbb{R}$.

---

Why can we do that? Clearly, there exists a $\operatorname{P}$-null set $N\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ such that $(1)$ is continuous for all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N$. Moreover, I know that we can alter measurable functions on null sets without changing their measure related properties. However, is it guaranteed that we can alter $B$ on all null sets on which $(1)$ is not continuous such that $(1)$ is continuous for all $\omega\in\Omega$?

---

Remark: Maybe we can use the *Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem* to prove that $(1)$ can indeed be assumed as continuous for all $\omega\in\Omega$. The theorem can be formulated as follows:

Let $X=(X_t,t\ge 0)$ be a real-valued stochastic process such that for all $T>0$, there exists $\alpha,\beta,C>0$ with $$\operatorname{E}\left[\left|X_t-X_s\right|^\alpha\right]\le C|t-s|^{1+\beta}\;\;\;\text{for all }s,t\in [0,T]]$$ Then, there exists a *modification* of $X$ which is locally Hölder-continuous of order $\gamma\in \left(0,\frac \beta\alpha\right)$.

Stochastic processes $X,Y$ are called *modifications* of each other, if $X_t=Y_t$ almost surely.

Comment: Notice it's for almost all values of $\omega$, but for _all_, not just almost all, values of $t$.  If there were just one value of $t$ at which there is a discontinuity, that could change things a lot.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's clear to me. But if for at least one $\omega$, the mapping $X(\omega)$ in $(2)$ is not continuous, then $X$ cannot be viewed as a mapping into $C\left([0,\infty)\right)$. So, that's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, in probability theory you are free to excise null sets from the probability space. So you could define Brownian motion with a.s. continuous paths and then excise the null set where the paths are not continuous. Now the paths are always continuous. The process we've made is actually *indistinguishable* from the a.s. continuous process: their entire trajectories are equal with probability $1$. This is a stronger notion than just being modifications of one another.

It is important in this procedure that we are *not* excising a null set for each $t$, we are excising a *single* null set which encapsulates all the paths that have any discontinuities at any point. Since this point is so important, I will rephrase it again: Brownian motion is *not* merely continuous at each fixed point of time a.s., it is continuous over all time a.s.

Comment: The random paths of the approach based on iterative refinement at dyadic points (the approach in Paul Lévy's works) are only almost surely continuous.

Comment: @Did You're right, let me fix that.

Comment: Clearly, there is a $\operatorname P$-null set $N$ such that $$t\mapsto B_t(\omega)$$ is continuous, for all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N$. However, why can we always modify $t\mapsto B_t(\omega)$ for some $\omega\in N$ such that this path is continuous? Could it happen, that there is no way to modify the path in such a way?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You don't modify any paths. You ignore the discontinuous paths entirely, by redefining your sample space to be $\Omega \setminus N$. What would it even mean to modify a path?

Comment: Given a process $X$ whose paths satisfy a desired property with probability one. Can we always treat $X$ as a process whose paths satisfies this property? In particular, can we always treat the Brownian motion $B$ as being continuous? It seems like this should be true, if we can always modify $X$ on a null set, such that the modified process is indistinguishable from $X$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Provided the null set doesn't matter to you, sure. But you don't really modify it on the null set at all, you just cut that null set out of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Besides excising your null set on which the paths are discontinuous, you can also redefine your process to take the constant value 0 (or any other fixed continuous function) on the null set.